# Twitter api and retweets

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to get the last tweet from the people I follow using the twitter api (`http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends.json&screen_name=[username]`), but I noticed that if the user's last tweet is a retweet, the json data does not contain a "status" element.

Using the "user timeline" api does not work either, the last tweet is the last non retweeted tweet.

Is there a way to get the real last status, even if it's a RT, through the twitter API?

Comment: If you're working with APIs, this really oughta be on http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was addressed recently by the Twitter devs. You can now add a `include_rts=true` to your call to user_timeline. See the full discussion here: http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/7a4be385ff549ed0